# How to change or delete link line HTML DOM

Tags: html

[image]

You see the `stackoverflow.com` inside of the red border? I know that it can be changed by HTML DOM but I don't know how.

Comment: That's the browser's status bar. You can't change it by any means other than changing the HTML of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't be changed.  What you could do is is not create a link but instead have an element with style="cursor:pointer" with a click handler that navigator to another page.  That's kind of evil though and breaks things like search engines and accessibility

Comment: I know that, look what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/xaqobuni/1/
I don't want that the status bar shows the link because it's a button.
Thanks anyway